# tools - Free Windows Memory Toolkit for x64

Tags: memory, digital-forensics

I have seen the Moonsols Memory Toolkit for Windows (Community Edition). It however does not support x64 memory dumping. Only its professional version can do that. Are there any free alternatives out there that do the same ? To narrow down what I am looking for I would be interested in features like -:

- Convert a memory dump from a x64 Architecture.
- Convert or decompress Windows 7 hibernation files.
- Convert a Windows 7 memory dump.

I have seen a lot of free tools for x86, but for x64 its a whole different ball game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Volatility](http://code.google.com/p/volatility/) supports x64 Windows 7 hibernation files as well as x64 images.

Comment: What about Win8 x64 hibernation files ?

Comment: Win8 hibernation file is a Volatility project WIP see: https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility/issues/25 and https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility/issues/176#issuecomment-73629801

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Moonsols Dumpit?  It is a free utility that can grab the physical memory.

http://www.moonsols.com/2011/07/18/moonsols-dumpit-goes-mainstream/

Rekall might be able to help with the acquisition piece as well.

http://www.rekall-forensic.com/index.html

Comment: Do they support x64 ?

Comment: Also do any of the allow the editing of x64 Windows hibernation files ?

Comment: You can download winpmem from the Rekall project for dumping Win x64 memory directly form here: https://github.com/google/rekall/releases/download/v1.0rc11/winpmem_1.6.0.exe

Comment: @jonasl Just bear with me then. I use recall to dump the Winx64 memory and I analyze that using Volatility. Am I doing the right thing then ?

Comment: @Sreyan no Rekall is a fork (rewrite) of Volatility from Google so basically you're going to use it like Volatility

Comment: @Maijin So basically I can both dump the memory and analyze it with it right ? I won't be needing any other tools.

Comment: @Sreyan Volatility/Rekall doesn't dump memory, please read the docs http://www.rekall-forensic.com/docs/Manual/tutorial.html && https://code.google.com/p/volatility/wiki/VolatilityUsage23

Comment: @Maijin Then how do I dump my RAM memory ? Does Moonsols DumpIt allow x64 memory dumping ?

Comment: @Sreyan http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools:Memory_Imaging would show you that winpmem part of the **rekall framework** for example is doing this job quite easily https://github.com/google/rekall/releases/v1.0rc11/

Answer (score 0):

Mandiant Redline might be helpful as well.

https://www.mandiant.com/resources/download/redline